# Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging Plugin Push notification sometimes not working for iOS 13.3

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

My tools and plugin versions are as follows:

iPad - iOS 13.3

Visual studio - 8.3.11

Xcode - 10.3

Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging - Version 3.1.2

I had the code working for iOS 12.2. I have my iOS upgraded to 13.3 now. I'm not sure when the notification stopped working for iOS. I doubt the version iOS 13.3. When I start debugging very rarely the notification works.

But most of the time the app doesn't hit RegisteredForRemoteNotifications or FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications methods. I'm not sure whats going wrong. I spent around 2 days working on the same :(

I'm not even able to upgrade the plugin. If I upgrade, I'm facing linking error. Please suggest if anyone came across same issue

Comment: Try to send push notification with firebase console. Check if this happens again. This way you may find the culprit (server code or client). Narrow it down, then share some code here. Firebase has not any bug like that as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Iman It's not hitting RegisteredForRemoteNotifications itself. I tried sending notification from console too. But no use

Comment: @Iman I've updated the question. Please share your thoughts

Comment: @AkshayKumar Hi , maybe[this disussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58198340/firebase-push-notifications-dont-work-on-ios-13) will be helpful .You can have a try .

Comment: ios 13 had a lot of changes in APN (apple push notification) like a new attribute in header (`apns-push-types`) and so on. You should revise your code. And I don’t know what Xamarin version works find here.

Comment: With recent changes in iOS you should use Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging 4.1.1.1  minimum. With Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.InstanceID 4.2.1

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT
Thanks for your response. It's working for me now with revising the code as mentioned by Iman

Comment: @Adlorem
Thanks for your response. It's working for me now with revising the code as mentioned by Iman. So I didn't try your solution

Comment: @AkshayKumar Okey , glad solved it ! Later you can update this as an answer then other people will know that :-)