# Firebase notifications received on iOS 12 but not received on iOS 13

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, ios13, ios12

Firebase push notifications sent but not received on iOS 13 and received on iOS 12

My xcode version 11.4 with Swift 5

I did the test on iOS 12.4.2, 13.4 and 13.4.1

The notifications not received in any app state (foreground, background and closed)

I added a firebase project for my project and connected with APNS using both ways APNs auth key and APNs Certificates

I tried the firebase notification composer and got the same result

Here is my AppDelegate class code:

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import Firebase
import NMAKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        //Firebase
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        // [START set_messaging_delegate]
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        // [END set_messaging_delegate]

        // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
        // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // [END register_for_notifications]

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.

    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.            
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }

    // [START receive_message]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
    // If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
    // the FCM registration token.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

        var token = ""

        for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
            token += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])
        }

        print("Token: ", token)

        print("APNs token retrieved: \(token)")
        //print("content---\(token)");

        //APNS token // not firebase token
        UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: kAPNSToken)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

        print(deviceToken)

        // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
        //Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }
}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)


        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {

    // [START refresh_token]
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {

        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]

        UserDefaults.standard.set(fcmToken, forKey: kFCMToken)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: CustomNotification.fcmToken, object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)

    }
    // [END refresh_token]


    // [START ios_10_data_message]
    // Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.
    // To enable direct data messages, you can set Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel to true.
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }
    // [END ios_10_data_message]
}
```

...

Here are my app capabilities:
[image: App Capabilities]

...

I read this article about iOS 13 push notifications changes :

[OS 13 and Xcode 11 Changes That Affect Push Notifications](https://onesignal.com/blog/ios-13-introduces-4-breaking-changes-to-notifications/)

(regarding priority and apns-push-type)

I tried the following payload (and tried many different payloads forms) with no luck:

```
{
    "to": "d2qB-YP_c0B0giLCUFKf1A:APA91bEe....",
    "message": {
        "notification": {
            "title": "Match update",
            "body": "Arsenal goal in added time, score is now 3-0"
        },
        "android": {
            "ttl": "86400s",
            "notification": {
                "click_action": "OPEN_ACTIVITY_1"
            }
        },
        "apns": {
            "headers": {
                "apns-priority": "5",
                "apns-push-type": "background"
            },
            "payload": {
                "aps": {
                    "category": "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY"
                }
            }
        },
        "webpush": {
            "headers": {
                "TTL": "86400"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used also the following payloads:

```
{
    "to": "d2qB-YP_c0B0giLCUFKf1A:APA91bEe....",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Match update",
        "body": "Arsenal goal in added time, score is now 3-0"
    }
}
```

And

```
{
    "to": "eyjFrVn6iEagjBHdxb9sDN.....",
    "notification": {
        "title": "my title here",
        "text": "body here here",
        "sound": "default",
        "badge": 1
    },
    "data": {
        "custom": "my custom message"
    }
}
```

And unfortunately, I got the same result.

Comment: Hi Ahmad. The payload structure you're using is for FCM v1. Could you try using legacy and see if you still cant send to both versions? [Here's a sample to send a push using Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45310143/4625829). `to` is no longer a reserved key inside a payload for v1. Strange that it doesn't work on iOS13, might also be an OS level restriction, but do let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you AL. for your clarification, I used the firebase composer, and the message received to iOS 12 but unfortunately not received for iOS 13

Comment: Also, I tried using legacy and got the same result

{"to":"eyjFrVn6iEagjBHdxb9sDN.....","notification":{"title":"my title here","text":"body here here"}}

https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.6c791ea578a9484680bc83bec7f187af

Comment: I used also different syles like:

https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.c9ab9f5735da4e348143257feaffb88f

and 

https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.cb7454324c244e2ab076f81987ed108f

Comment: Maybe an issue with iOS 13 itself: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1041 Also, have you seen the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58198340/4625829)? Maybe adding the options in the payload could make a difference.

Comment: Thank you AL., yes I tried this solution also, and still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looked like there is an issue in Firebase - APNS integration using the auth key method (at least for my case with the bellow information)

The test made on XCode version 11.4, iOS 12.4.2, 13.4 and 13.4.1

**There is an issue in Firebase push notifications when using the auth key and should use the p12 certificates instead**

I checked direct APNS push notifications (without firebase) it's working fine

I checked also using 2 methods APNS auth key and p12 certificates, it worked on p12 certificates but not for auth key

Comment: The answer checked and verified carefully, and I can confirm that there is an issue with Firebase - Auth Key method for iOS 13

Comment: Why did you delete your other answer?

Comment: I updated the written the answer in a more professional way, I got a vote down for the previous answer although it's correct, I tried to edit the answer but unfortunately the vote down not removed although the answer tested and verified carefully

Comment: Yes, fair enough — the downvote was the problem! I think your approach here is right, sorry for the noise.

Comment: Omg this is such a big flaw in Firebase's documentation. You have no idea how many hours I've used to debug this issue. Thank you so much, didnt think that using the SSL certificates would fix this but it did!